# how to get frequency of Object's field in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I try this code to print out the frequency of name "John"in the list(Human has 2 field: name and age):

```
package test;
import data.Boy;
import data.Human;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Human> menu = new ArrayList();
       menu.add(new Human("John",20));
       menu.add(new Human("Smith",19));
       menu.add(new Human("Alice",12));
       menu.add(new Human("John",18));
       System.out.println(Collections.frequency(menu, menu.get(0).getName());

}
}
```

But the value is 0 instead of 2.Which's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2):

[`Collections#frequency`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) would be appropriate if you wanted to count how many times a particular `Human` *object* appeared in your list.  But you want to check the count of humans having a particular *name*, regardless of whether that name might occur in more than one object.  Streams come in handy here:

```
List<Human> matches = menu.stream()
                          .filter(h -> h.getName().equals(menu.get(0).getName()))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

int size = matches == null ? 0 : matches.size();
System.out.println("There are " + size + " humans which match.");
```

Comment: Tks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Well, `menu` contains `Human` objects, not Strings, which is what's presumably returned by `getName()`. Therefore, `Collections.frequency()` will check if `menu` contains "John", but it doesn't - it instead contains a **Human** with the name "John".

Comment: Oh,I see your comment.